# Alamofire raw json string to post or put

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

How can i send raw json string from put or post method with Alamofire?

I can't find any example for that.

```
let params = Mapper().toJSONString(results) // json string with array of objects

Alamofire.request(.PUT, Config().apiGroup, parameters: params)
```

getting error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]?'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alamofire expect a dictionary of `[String: AnyObject]?` as your error said and according to your code you are trying to pass an array, you need to convert it to a dictionary instead. Check the signature of the function `request` in Alamofire:

```
func request(method: Method, _ URLString: URLStringConvertible, 
             parameters: [String : AnyObject]? = default, 
             encoding: ParameterEncoding = default, 
              headers: [String : String]? = default) -> Request
```

See this example from the [Alamofire doc](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire):

```
let params = Mapper().toJSONString(results) // json string with array of objects

Alamofire.request(.PUT, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["params": params])
     .response { request, response, data, error in
         print(request)
         print(response)
         print(data)
         print(error)
      }
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: But that is array of objects, so i can't convert it  to `[String: AnyObject]`. :/

Comment: Yes but as I said above Alamofire expect a Dictionary not an array, see updated answer to you can see an example

Comment: But i am trying `.POST` or `.PUT`. This is example or data array: `[["id": 10, "order": 0, "name": Test], ["id": 12, "order": 9, "name": Test2]]` i can't convert this to `[String: AnyObject]`

Comment: See updated answer in the example, you're trying to send an array of JSON and Alamofire not accept this as parameter, you can create a dictionary with the array and some key, like in the example and it should work. But you need to know the exact parameter in your server side to parse the JSON, be careful.

Comment: Ohhh, its too bad that i need this "params" :(

Comment: params is just a name but yes you need a key

Comment: The point that @MirzaDelic was trying to make is that the Alamofire API is deficient in this regard, because it is valid JSON for the top-level container to be an array, instead of an object with a key and value. If your API expects an array of objects, and you can't change the API, how do you encode this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @Granola `Mapper` is a class of the user that asked the question that returns the json string with array of objects, nothing more